# Заполнение двумерного ArrayList java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] test = new Integer[3];
        test[0] = 2;
        test[1] = 3;
        test[2] = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        arrayList.add(test);
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.println(arrayList.get(i)[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он возвращал полный двумерный массив?
Сейчас просто возвращает 2, надо 2 3 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам во вложенном цикле, нужно итерироваться пока не перечислите все элементы i-того элемента листа. Поэтому нужно добавить .get(i)

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] test = new Integer[3];
        test[0] = 2;
        test[1] = 3;
        test[2] = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        arrayList.add(test);
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size();i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.get(i).length; j++)  //ТУТ!!!
            {
                System.out.println(arrayList.get(i)[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если стояла задача вывода содержимого списка массивов, проще было бы воспользоваться циклами `foreach`:

```java
for (Integer[] arr : arrayList) {
    for (Integer n : arr) {
        System.out.print(n);
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

или же выводить массивы-элементы при помощи `Arrays.toString`:

```java
for (Integer[] arr : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```